# How do I get the key of previous ordered rows with an unknown offset?

Tags: sql-server

I am working with an ERP that stores its retail sales and any discounts related to that sale as separate lines in the same table.

Product lines are identified by a line type of 0 whereas discount lines are a line type of 6, and loyalty discount is a line type of 7.

Unfortunately, the discount records do not have any direct relation back to the product line that the discount applies to.

I need to extract this data and for the discount lines, provide the key for the product line that it applies to.

Discount Lines (6 and 7) ALWAYS come up after 0 LineType and can be identified by the sequence number. For example, in my table below, the second and third line are discounts for the first line because they have a LineType of 6 and 7 that come after LineType 0.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80249

I need my results to look like this:

```
Id     LineType     SequenceNumber    Description              ProductLineId
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1      0            1                 Product A                NULL
2      6            2                 Discount on Product A    1
3      7            3                 Loyalty Discount         1
4      0            4                 Product B                NULL
5      0            5                 Product C                NULL
6      6            6                 Discount on Product C    5
```

I know I can use a `LAG` function, however the offset is not known, as there may be more discounts. I am currently using a cursor similar to the below which is working, but got awfully slow (the below is the same concept however it sets a Flag against the data, not the ID of the record:

```
OPEN SalesLines
FETCH NEXT FROM SalesLines INTO @SourceKey, @HeaderSourceKey, @IsMarkedDownFlag, @LineSequenceNumber, @RetailLineTypeId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  IF @RetailLineTypeId = 1 OR @CurrentHeaderSourceKey != @HeaderSourceKey
  BEGIN
    SET @CurrentIsMarkedDownFlag = @IsMarkedDownFlag
    SET @CurrentHeaderSourceKey = @HeaderSourceKey
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    IF @CurrentIsMarkedDownFlag != @IsMarkedDownFlag
    BEGIN
      UPDATE @RawData
      SET IsMarkedDown = @CurrentIsMarkedDownFlag
      WHERE SourceKey = @SourceKey
    END
  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT s.*, productLine.Id as ProductLineId FROM Sales s
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 s1.Id FROM Sales s1  
             WHERE s1.SequenceNumber < s.SequenceNumber AND s1.LineType=0  AND s.LineType>0
             ORDER BY SequenceNumber DESC) as productLine
```

Creating index on `SequenceNumber` and `LineType` can speed it up.

Comment: Perfect! I had in the back of my head an outer apply but didn't look further into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick try, but i think it provides the desired output. Any improvements are welcome!

```
;WITH products
AS
(SELECT Id, SequenceNumber
FROM    sales
WHERE   LineType = 0)

SELECT  s.Id, s.LineType, s.SequenceNumber, s.Description, p.Id AS ProductLineId
FROM    sales s
        LEFT JOIN products p 
            ON p.SequenceNumber = 
                (SELECT MAX(SequenceNumber) FROM products p2 
                   WHERE p2.SequenceNumber < s.SequenceNumber)
                AND s.LineType <> 0
```

Answer (score -2):

Find next lines with type <> 0 which less than next 0 line

edited